# Is it possible to delete a DynamoDB item based on secondary index with Python Boto3 lib?

Tags: python, boto, boto3

Is it possible to delete an item from DynamoDB using the Python Boto3 library by specifying a secondary index value? I won't know the primary key in advance, so is it possible to skip the step of querying the index to retrieve the primary key, and just add a condition to the delete request that includes the secondary index value?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, as of now it's not possible.

You have to specify the primary key to delete an item, although you can optionally pass `ConditionExpression` to prevent it from being deleted if some condition is not met. Only this much flexibility api is providing us.